# Python: Get Max Value in a List of Sets

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get max value in a list of sets in 2.7.

I'm using this syntax:

```
myListOfSets = [set([1441134315L]), set([1448405794L])]

myValue = max(list(myListOfSets))
>> myValue
>> set([1441134315L])
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why `set([1441134315L])` ?..

Comment: *this syntax* looks isn't valid syntax in Python.

Comment: @KevinGuan It's valid aside from accidentally switching from using the name `maxValue` to `myValue`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? You start with a list of sets and you want, what? The largest number out of all sets? The largest number from the largest set? Why do you have a list of sets of single numbers? Please explain your use case and intent so people can answer.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: Ah, invalid syntax in Python 3, but no problem in Python 2.7.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan you are right, my bad while write the question, i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you want I would do something like this - find the maximal value of each set and then find the maximum of those values -

```
max_all_sets = max([max(a) for a in myListOfSets])
```

Comment: Or simply: `max(myListOfSets, key=max)`.

Comment: That depends on what he wants to get - the set with the maximal value or the maximal value

Answer (score 1):

an `itertools` solution:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> max(chain(*myListOfSets)
```